# How do I link my Git to GitHub as a remote repository, without receiving the Fatal Error?

Tags: git, github

So I am a beginner and I just got started with Git and GitHub. I learnt that you have to link your GitHub as the remote repository in Git by using the Git remote command. But when I say git remote add origin and the link for my repository, I get an error that says

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Is there something I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

This problem states that the repository that you are trying to use is not a git repo. Are you sure that you are in the right directory, did you also run `git init` inside of the dir , this would make the dir a git repo?

Comment: Oops...I edited your answer on accident instead of my own. I rolled it back to your original now.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the current folder does not contain a git repository. You either need to `cd` to a folder that actually contains a repo or run `git init` in a directory where you want to create a new repository.

For future reference, googling an error message will often answer your question immediately.